# Converting a list of str into list of int python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following input:

```
669  866  147
 15  881  210
662   15   70
```

Using `.split('\n')` on it, I am able to get a list of 3 strings. Then I would like to break each string to a list of strings and then convert those to int.
The code I'm trying to use for this so far is

```
for tr in numbers:
    tr = tr.split()
    tr = list(map(int, tr))
```

However, after the for loop closes nothing happened to the original list, so if I run this command `print(type(numbers[0]))` it returns `<class 'str'>`.

I am guessing this is due to the operation happening inside the loop so outside it nothing changed, so how would I go about making it so the original list updates too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to explicitly set the lists back to the numbers list, right now, you are only manipulating a variable tr with re-assignment, so the original list doesn't get affected. Try this instead

```
>>> numbers = ["669  866  147", " 15  881  210", "662   15   70"]
>>> for idx, tr in enumerate(numbers):
...     tr = tr.split()
...     numbers[idx] = list(map(int, tr))
... 
>>> numbers
[[669, 866, 147], [15, 881, 210], [662, 15, 70]]
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you for explaining as well I perfectly understand now, much appreciated!

Comment: @AngelosH Happy to help, don't forget to [accept and upvote the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Comment: Generally more idiomatic to use a list comp: `numbers[idx] = [int(n) for n in tr.split()]`

Comment: @BenHoyt Agreed, though I just wanted to do minimal number of changes so its easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner for this could be like this:

```
In [6]: numbers = "669 866 147\n15 881 210\n662 15 70"

In [7]: [[int(y) for y in x.split()] for x in numbers.split('\n')]
Out[7]: [[669, 866, 147], [15, 881, 210], [662, 15, 70]]
```

You can assign In [7] directly back to numbers, or into a separate new variable.

Comment: Yep this works very nicely too, thanks for the one-liner!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
numbers = ["669  866 ASSASSA 147", " 15  881  210", "662   15   70"]
numbers = [[int(_str) for _str in re.findall(r"\d+", o)] for o in numbers]
print numbers
# [[669, 866, 147], [15, 881, 210], [662, 15, 70]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Pythonic way would be to use a list comprehension - avoiding enumeration/indexing, mutation and a new variable in the scope:

```
>>> numbers = ["669  866  147", " 15  881  210", "662   15   70"]
>>> numbers = [map(int, tr.split()) for tr in numbers]
>>> numbers
[[669, 866, 147], [15, 881, 210], [662, 15, 70]]
```

Some people avoid the `map` builtin, in which case you could substitute the second line with this:

```
numbers = [[int(n) for n in tr.split()] for tr in numbers]
```